# Cancelling a sent transaction if user doesn't sign it before a condition is matched

Tags: transaction, confirmtransaction

I'm using @solana/web3.js in react and I wanna know if there is a way of cancelling a sent transaction waiting to be signed by the user if a condition is matched before that user signs it through his wallet.

```
        let tx = new Transaction().add(
            createTransferCheckedInstruction(
                new PublicKey(mapedVariables['userATA']), // from (should be a token account)
                new PublicKey(process.env.REACT_APP_TOKEN_MINT), // mint
                new PublicKey(process.env.REACT_APP_ATA), // to (should be a token account)
                wallet.publicKey, // from's owner
                value_bought * 1e8, // amount, if your deciamls is 8, send 10^8 for 1 token
                8 // decimals
            )


            signature = await sendTransaction(tx, connection);
            await connection.confirmTransaction(signature, 'processed');
            if(condition matched){CANCEL TRANSACTION}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you use `sendTransaction` to send a transaction to the wallet, it can't be canceled because it's up to the wallet to send the transaction (after approval by the user).

If you need to perform conditional checks related to the connected wallet, you can use the `publicKey` of the wallet before building and sending the transaction.

Comment: I followed your advice and make the user sign the transaction with:

window.solana.signTransaction(tx) in a Promise.race so if a counter gets to 0 the signing gets rejected and the sendTransaction doesn't execute.

I'm just wondering which is the way FFF raffle for example does to show a message that the tx can't be simulated in the prompted message on the wallet extension and rejects it like that.
Thanks for the quick answer :)